# GCP: How to check/find logs for metadata added in Google Cloud Platform project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Want to find logs for Metadata added for google cloud project i.e. Project Metadata, not for compute/VM instance metadata.

Tried to find in stack-driver logging but it has showing only for compute instances like as `compute.instances.setMetadata` or `compute.instances.insert` or `compute.instances.delete` etc.

I am looking for metadata or property added in/for GCP project(Not for VM instance metadata). Reason behind this, someone is adding/modifying property and we are unable to find the history to track this change and it causes to failure of application.

Comment: I would also recommend checking the activity and logs console to find information from the logs. However there may be a large number of information on those logs which may be difficult to go through. If you can mention the specific property that you are looking for, it would be more practical to give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, you can add the following to your query to look for project metadata:

```
protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at the Activity page - https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity

The Logs console also has a `Google Project` resource that you can filer on.